# Select an element based on the element that succeeds it

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there any selector string in jQuery that lets me filter a set by selecting only elements which have a certain element after them?

For example, if I have a set that looks like this:

```
[div, div, span, div, div, div, span, div, span, div]
```

And I only wanted to select the divs that precede a span, how could I do this in a single selector string if it is at all possible? Is there something like this:

```
$("div:preceding(span)")
```

It's not a huge deal but I was just curious. Currently, I'm just looping through the set and checking each element to see if it is a div and the the element right after it (selected by using .next()) is a span, then if it is I just add it to an empty set created before I started the loop. Is this the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
$('span').prev('div');
```

Matches all the `div` whose next immediate sibling element is a `span`.

Comment: Well... I'm embarrassed. I can't believe I didn't think of that. I don't know why I did my own loop when I knew most of jQuery's functions like this that help filter sets loop themselves. Thanks!

Comment: ok. I'd already done the fiddle but you answered while I was doing it, seemed daft to post exactly the same answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to use a selector for the broad set (not looking at what is after it) and then use `.filter()` to remove the items that don't have the desired element after them.

I'm not aware of a selector that will implement anything like `$("div:preceding(span)")`.

It is possible to implement your own custom verbs like `preceding` in the jQuery selector support, but doing so is probably more trouble than just using `.filter()` like this:

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return($(this).next("span").length != 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go, your custom selector `:preceding`
you can use exactly like you desired (e.g:): `$('div:preceding(span)').css({color: 'red'});`

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/emamaz/2/edit)

```
$.expr[":"].preceding = function(e, i, m) {
   return $(e).next(m[3]).length;
};
```

Comment: I like the approach but since, at least for my purposes, I only need to do this once, I'm going to go with @Sushanth's code. Thanks though.

Comment: @Brandon oh well... you're welcome, at least one day if you'll need how to create your own custom stuff, you'll find it easily ;)